# Kotlin testing authentication to /actuator api

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-actuator, mockmvc

I have a `ActuatorSecurity` class which I use for authentication for `/actuator` actions.

```
package com.netapp.qronicle.config

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class ActuatorSecurity : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Value("\${security.user.actuator-username}")
    private val actuatorUsername: String? = null

    @Value("\${security.user.actuator-password}")
    private val actuatorPassword: String? = null

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf().disable().requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        val passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()
        val encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(actuatorPassword)

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(actuatorUsername).password(encodedPassword).roles("USER")
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        // ALTHOUGH THIS SEEMS LIKE USELESS CODE,
        // IT'S REQUIRED TO PREVENT SPRING BOOT AUTO-CONFIGURATION
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }
}
```

I have everything configured in my `application.properties` file

```
# spring boot actuator access control
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
security.user.actuator-username=admin
security.user.actuator-password=admin123
```

I would like to just to do basic `authentication` api tests for `/actuator/**` but have not been able to do so, here is my test class

```
package com.netapp.qronicle.web

import com.netapp.qronicle.config.ActuatorSecurity
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers
import javax.inject.Inject

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@WebMvcTest(ActuatorSecurity::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [ActuatorSecurity::class])

class ActuatorTest {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Test
    fun `Basic authentication actuator test`() {
        val result = mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/actuator"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
        Assertions.assertNotNull(result)
    }
}
```

The error thrown is:

```
2019-02-26 17:07:26.062  INFO 34766 --- [           main] com.netapp.qronicle.web.ActuatorTest     : Starting ActuatorTest on jmasson-mac-0 with PID 34766 (started by jonma in /Users/jonma/Development/java/report-generator)
2019-02-26 17:07:26.099  INFO 34766 --- [           main] com.netapp.qronicle.web.ActuatorTest     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-02-26 17:07:29.324  INFO 34766 --- [           main] com.netapp.qronicle.web.ActuatorTest     : Started ActuatorTest in 4.468 seconds (JVM running for 6.427)

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /actuator
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Comment: You get a http 404 error

Comment: That endpoint surely exists, so I don't get this error!